# How to parse XML using C# when XML contains same element again?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

I am trying to read an XML file which is looking like,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MyXML>
<SESSION FORM_ID="775938" CID="" ID="HAKKI-LAPTOP_634975758376381105">
<FIELD NAME="A001DATE_M" Y="2.32" X="5.5" WIDTH="7.15" HEIGHT="0.99">First Value</FIELD>
<FIELD NAME="A002" Y="2.32" X="17.83" WIDTH="2.38" HEIGHT="0.99">Second Value</FIELD>
<FIELD NAME="A003" Y="1.11" X="17.83" WIDTH="2.38" HEIGHT="0.99">Third Value</FIELD>
<FIELD NAME="A004" Y="1.11" X="5.5" WIDTH="2.38" HEIGHT="0.99">Fourth Value</FIELD>
</SESSION> 
</MyXML>
```

I am trying to read the read the third value.
My Code ables to retrieve the first value.

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(sXMLPath);
XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("MyXML/SESSION/FIELD");
if (node != null)
{
     MessageBox.Show(node.InnerText);
}
```

What Changes do I need to make in order to read the third or fourth value?

**Solution:** (Provided by @DGibbs)

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(sXMLPath);
var elem = (from n in xml.Descendants("FIELD")
            where n.Attribute("NAME").Value == "A004"
            select n).FirstOrDefault();
MessageBox.Show(elem.Value);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use LINQ to XML and select by the `NAME` attribute:

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(fileLocation);

var elem = (from n in xml.Descendants("FIELD")
            where n.Attribute("NAME").Value == "A004"
            select n.Value).FirstOrDefault();
```

Note that you need to update your XML `FIELD` elements as they are self closing and also have closing tags.

Example:

```
<FIELD NAME="A002" Y="2.32" X="17.83" WIDTH="2.38" HEIGHT="0.99" />Second Value</FIELD>
```

Should be:

```
<FIELD NAME="A002" Y="2.32" X="17.83" WIDTH="2.38" HEIGHT="0.99">Second Value</FIELD>
```

Comment: I can able to retrieve the entire tag with this code. How to retrieve only the value?

Comment: See my edit. You just need to select the `Value` property of the element

Comment: I have retrieved using the `Value` Property. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Extend your [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) selector with `[3]`:

```
XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("MyXML/SESSION/FIELD[3]");
```

Comment: for using this code, I need to know the series, may be the above answer will help much better. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> You can use **DGibbs answer** or try like this if you need all the fields
>   as a list.,

Get all the `FIELDS` into the List and Do whatever you want.,

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(sXMLPath);

IEnumerable<XElement> elmList = xml.Descendants("FIELD");

foreach (XElement elm in elmList)
{
    // Your Logics goes Here      
}
```